# What is the difference between this site and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

When I was a student not too long ago I posted all of my questions on SO, so Im just wondering how this site is suppose to be different? What should I post here instead of on SO? It seems like this site is a bit more research oriented, but most research questions are rather broad and would be bad for SE sites.

Comment: The answer becomes quite clear once you understand what CS is in contrast to programming, hence I think the linked question is enough for you. If you still have questions after reading that one, please incorporate that into your question and we can reopen. Imho, CS questions are offtopic *and* usually ill-treated on [SO] so there is little reason to post there instead of here. Note that "takes place at a university" is not the same as "research questions"; in fact, the overwhelming majority of questions regards undergrad course material. That's not by design but what it's currently like.

Comment: Not sure whether it's bad form to comment on closed questions, but the system allows it. There was actually some controversy when the site's charter was being finalized what the policy should w.r.t. programming should be. Raphael's view of the CS/programming divide wasn't the only one proposed, but it was the one that the majority went with. I was pretty firmly in the other camp, that the content of a programming question determines whether it is CS. The dupe'd question has relevant discussion.